# Execute jquery code depending on media queries

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I'm not really good with coding. Just want to ask if this would be possible? I found a code here in one of the threads here inside stack:

```
[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldn7qkqv/)
```

Would it be possible to execute the code depending on the width of the browser window?

Like for example on 1280 pixels width,the above code will execute on a different value of scrolling height,

Then on 981 pixels width, the above code again will run using another different scrolling height value.

I tried using a plugin (enquire.js) but can't seem to make it work? Would appreciate any tips or some guide.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A better approach then the window's width, is to use the lightweight [enquire.js plugin](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). Unlike window width, enquire will use the values that correspond to actual CSS media queries. For instance, a browser may return a different size for window width (jQuery) than for the CSS media requirement. Enquire.js fixes that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var width=$(window).width();
```

you can use this to check width and apply css or code you want to execute according to width but it will require refreshing  windows every time you shifts windows width

```
    if(width<750){
.........
}else{
.........
}
```

Comment: Yes simple but effective. The guide I was looking for. Thanks Amit.